# Inutitive explanation for why my crude approximation of a probability approaches exactly half of the exact value

Tags: probability, combinatorics, approximation, intuition

First, an introductory question:

> There are $3n$ couples. The $6n$ people are each randomly allocated to one of three rooms, so that each room has $2n$ people. What is the probability that every couple is separated?

I made a **crude approximation** for large $n$: $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{3n}$, because (assuming for the sake of simplicity that each couple consists of a husband and a wife) for each husband, there is an approximately $\frac{2}{3}$ chance that his wife is in a different room.

My question is:

> It turns out that my approximation approaches exactly half of the exact value, as $n\to\infty$. Is there an intuitive explanation for this?

In case you're interested, the exact value is $\dfrac{\binom{3n}{2n}\binom{2n}{n}2^{3n}}{\binom{6n}{2n}\binom{4n}{2n}}$. Explanation:

- The denominator is the total number of ways to divide the $6n$ people
  into three rooms. First, among the $6n$ people, we choose $2n$ people
  to go to the first room, so $\binom{6n}{2n}$. Then among the
  remaining $4n$ people we choose $2n$ people to go to the second room, so
  $\binom{4n}{2n}$. Then the remaining $2n$ people go to the third
  room.
- The numerator is the total number of ways in which each couple is
  separated. First, among the $3n$ couples, we choose $2n$ couples to
  each be represented in the first room (one person from each couple),
  so $\binom{3n}{2n}$. Then we allocate the $n$ remaining couples into
  the second and third rooms (each room getting one member of each of
  these couples), so the second room must now get an additional $n$
  people, and these are chosen among the $2n$ people whose spouse went
  to the first room, so $\binom{2n}{n}$. Then the remaining $n$ people
  go to the third room. Then each couple has two ways of being separated among two rooms, so
  $2^{3n}$.

It can be shown algebraically or by [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Limit%5BDivide%5B%5C%2840%293n%5C%2841%29%21%2C%5C%2840%296n%5C%2841%29%21%5DPower%5B%5C%2840%29Divide%5B%5C%2840%292n%5C%2841%29%21%2Cn%21%5D%5C%2841%29%2C3%5DPower%5B27%2Cn%5D%2Cn-%3E%E2%88%9E%5D) that my approximation, $\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{3n}$, approaches exactly half of the exact value, as $n\to\infty$. I'm looking for an intuitive explanation.

(The introductory question was inspired by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4543477/old-maid-card-game-probability-question).)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I argue that there is no intuitive explanation, in the sense that the $2$ has a combinatorial background.

[Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) $n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}(n/e)^n$ and a very satisfying computation (since most terms cancel out) leaves you with twice your result. Most notably, the extra $2$ is the result of the leading square root term in Stirling's formula. Since this is a very low order contribution, it is rather a "relic" of taking the limit.

I do not argue that there is no interpretation. Terms like these usually have an impact on the variance of the limiting normal distribution in the CLT, which is then again the limit of the variances for the finite size laws. However, I don't think this was the (combinatorial) intuition you asked for.

Finally, here's an easier example to illustrate my point: the hypergeometric distribution, say $\binom{2n}{n}\binom{4n}{2n}/\binom{6n}{3n}\sim\sqrt{\frac{3}{2\pi}}$, i.e. the probability to get $n$ out for $2n$ hits when trying $3n$ out of $6n$ times.

Comment: Interesting that there might not be any intuitive explanation. I felt like one could say "Take $(\frac{2}{3})^{3n}$, but then you should double it because..."

Comment: That's what I called "combinatorial intuition". What you do in the first place is to drop dependencies, say for the last man standing it is determined if his wife will be in the same room or not, in the finite size case. In your model, there is no such thing. When you do not consider to many couples compared to the room sizes, your intuition is good, but when we fill up the rooms to the last seat, one has to be careful with approximations like these.

Comment: Yes, I see your point about the last man standing. I'll be interested to see if anyone else answers my question, either supporting your view or otherwise. Thanks.